# Realloc char* inside structure

Tags: c++, c, pointers, realloc

I'm new to C programming,
I have a structure with char and int pointer, I used to modify this pointer frequently, [found some reference in online to realloc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm) char* and its working fine, but same thing when I used inside structure mean problem arise,

```
typedef struct MyStruct
{
    int* intPtr;
    char* strPtr;
} Mystruct;
```

inside `main()`

```
Mystruct *myStructPtr;
myStructPtr = new Mystruct();
myStructPtr->intPtr = new int();
*myStructPtr->intPtr = 10;

myStructPtr->strPtr = (char *)malloc(sizeof("original"));
myStructPtr->strPtr = "original";
printf("String = %s,  Address = %u\n", myStructPtr->strPtr, myStructPtr->strPtr);

myStructPtr->strPtr = (char *)realloc(myStructPtr->strPtr, sizeof("modified original"));
myStructPtr->strPtr = "modified original";
printf("String = %s,  Address = %u\n", myStructPtr->strPtr, myStructPtr->strPtr);
```

I found following error while reallocating the char* inside pointer

> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in  or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

Comment: This is not C. C does not have `new` as keyword.

Comment: Why do you mix C with C++? both `new` and `malloc`?! Stick with one..

Comment: [The C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#mixing-malloc-and-delete)

Comment: I'm using C++ project, since I found difficulty in assigning new keyword for char* I'm using malloc here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is, after allocating memory

```
 myStructPtr->strPtr = (char *)malloc(sizeof("original"));
```

you're *overwriting* the returned pointer

```
myStructPtr->strPtr = "original";
```

and then, you try to use `realloc()` on a pointer which is not returned by a memory allocator function. This causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.5

> If `ptr` is a null pointer, the `realloc` function behaves like the `malloc` function for the
>   specified size. Otherwise, **if `ptr` does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory
>   management function**, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to the `free` or
>   `realloc` function, **the behavior is undefined.** [....]

That said, you should never use `%u` to print a *pointer* itself, youust use `%p` format specifier and cast teh corresponding argument to `(void *)`.

**Solution** You should either

- After malloc(), use [`strcpy()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to copy the content *into* the allocated memory region, pointed to by the returned pointer from `malloc()` call.
- get rid of `malloc()` and use *non-standard* [`strdup()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup).

Comment: Thanks for response @Sourav Ghosh, but if I use either strcpy() or strdup() this will create new address. I want my char* type to realloc size and value with same address. Is it possible? because I found char* address can maintain same address even after using realloc in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm

Comment: @ǨÅVËĔŊRĀǞĴĄŅ `strcpy()` never _creates_ any address, per se.

Comment: While using `strcpy()` it show assess violation error `Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`

Comment: Seems strcpy create new address on changing each time `String = original,  Address = 19193192
String = modified original1,  Address = 3236388`

Answer (score 2):

malloc allocates memory and stores the address in myStructPtr->strPtr. Then you reasign the pointer to the location of the string constant "original".

You cannot reallocate the location of the string consant.

Instead of assigning original to the pointer you should copy it to the location the pointer is pointing to.

```
const char* originalStr = "original";
memcpy ( myStructPtr->strPtr, originalStr , strlen(originalStr)+1 );
```